# Dual boot => Triple boot

Tags: dual-boot

A 256GB SSD has Windows-10 and 16.04 installed.  BIOS not UEFI.  A charity I work with requires me to use Quickbooks Desktop on Windows.  The plan is to ghost the existing system to a 512GB or larger SSD and create **a third bootable Windows 7  partition** for performing charity activities.

- Is this possible to have a third partition?
- Is there a good example you have used as a guide?
- Is triple booting with two Windows partitions different from 2 Linux partitions?

If you have done this before ([3 bootable partitions](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=ubuntu%20triple%20boot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) with GRUB) please indicate this in your response: lessons-learned are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: I have not, but issue is UEFI or BIOS. And Windows 7 DVD default install is BIOS only. You can copy to flash drive and move a few files around to make it UEFI bootable. Windows 7 or later uses BCD as menu for multiple booting. If system is BIOS best to have all Windows installs in primary partitions and Ubuntu in logical partitions. BIOS install: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1271600

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/860729/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-7-alongside-with-ubuntu-and-windows-10-dualboo?noredirect=1#comment1327830_860729

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible. I've had at least 5 operating system in parallel, at a time.

If you install Windows, it will not care about existing Linux installations. It will make your PC only boot Windows.

But fear not! You can boot into a live session, chroot into your existing Ubuntu installation, and update grub: [How do I run update-grub from a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd) This will make your PC boot all installed operating systems, again.

Because you intend to use more than one hard drive: Make sure to have your bios boot from the hard drive your Ubuntu installation is on with higher priority (further up) than the other hard drive.