I formatted the /boot/efi partition to upgrade Lubuntu and now I can't boot Windows
I have read several threads regarding this problem, but I can't solve mine.
Background
I wanted to upgrade my Lubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. My /boot/efi-partition's size was 150 MB and was working perfectly, but the Lubuntu 22.04 installer found an error: "/boot/efi partition has to be of at least 300 MB". So I went back, made my /swap partition 150 MB smaller, deleted the /boot/efi partition, and created it again but with a size of 300 MB. The installer accepted my manual partitioning and installed the OS.
Problem
My Lubuntu system works perfectly, but the "Windows Boot Manager" option on startup doesn't show up. The partition in which Windows 7 is installed remains untouched. The "Windows Boot Manager" option appeared yesterday and Windows 7 booted just fine.
Information
I did a lot of things, I can't really remember them all. I will leave you the information I believe is necessary after reading many threads and doing many things.

Partition structure: I have an SSD in which I run my Lubuntu 22.04 (/dev/sda3), and in which I used to run my Windows 7 (/dev/sda6). The Lubuntu 20.04 (/dev/sdb7 I think) is an old backup Linux I have for emergencies.
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0  74,2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1122
loop1     7:1    0  74,2M  1 loop /snap/core22/1380
loop2     7:2    0 262,5M  1 loop /snap/firefox/3779
loop3     7:3    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop4     7:4    0   497M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/141
loop5     7:5    0  91,7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop6     7:6    0  40,4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20671
loop7     7:7    0 139,7M  1 loop /snap/jdownloader2/20
loop8     7:8    0  38,8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
sda       8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   301M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2    8:2    0   3,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3    8:3    0    40G  0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
│                                 /
├─sda4    8:4    0    60G  0 part /home
├─sda5    8:5    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda6    8:6    0 119,4G  0 part 
sdb       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1    8:17   0    20G  0 part /home/el38/Descargas
├─sdb2    8:18   0    50G  0 part /home/el38/Documentos
├─sdb3    8:19   0   100G  0 part /home/el38/Imágenes
├─sdb4    8:20   0   100G  0 part /home/el38/Otros/misc
├─sdb5    8:21   0     1G  0 part 
├─sdb6    8:22   0     8G  0 part 
├─sdb7    8:23   0  43,6G  0 part 
├─sdb8    8:24   0  19,1G  0 part 
├─sdb9    8:25   0 377,1G  0 part /home/el38/Música
└─sdb10   8:26   0   807M  0 part 


sudo update-grub output
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-41-generic                                                                                                                   
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic                                                                                                                       
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic                                                                                                                   
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting                                                                                                   
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.                                                                                                
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.                                                                                
Found Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (20.04) on /dev/sdb7                                                                                                                           
done


sudo os-prober output:
/dev/sdb7:Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (20.04):Ubuntu:linux


/etc/fstab/ file. Note that for some reason there are two /boot/efi/ entries, with the same UUID, but one of them is commented. I did not do this manually, it is the original file that came with the install.
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
#UUID=F79B-717D                            /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=9e06d6ca-c62d-46a3-9002-f46ead7d60b3 swap           swap    defaults,discard 0 0
UUID=6f74b624-4306-4586-8913-d9328779bb27 /              ext4    defaults,discard 0 1
UUID=78cd0971-1d29-4878-b3b3-f95499c7c141 /home          ext4    defaults,discard 0 2
UUID=d72d820e-4479-4d9a-a742-c0cef3060ca9 /home/el38/Descargas ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=891ffb6e-ac93-4747-8d1e-e64661bd4805 /home/el38/Documentos ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=ddc43c37-870b-4d61-82dd-527bd6de118d /home/el38/Imágenes ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=af917f50-c22f-4fac-bb7b-9fdfeb65cae4 /home/el38/Otros/misc ext4    defaults   0 2
UUID=54b294eb-c768-4061-9488-4e79f52104ae /home/el38/Música ext4    defaults   0 2
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
UUID=F79B-717D  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1


I followed this guide and did what it said. I ran Boot-Repair in a live USB (the same I used to install my 22.04 new version in /dev/sda3). This is the Boot-Info diagnosis, and after running the recommended repair it said "Boot successfully repaired.", but the "Windows Boot Manager" option still does not appear and I can not boot Windows 7.
This is the Recommended Repair report.
I don't know if it's important, but after this recommended repair, Boot-Repair warned me about some "NVram locked". I searched this on the internet, and I read some people saying it is because of the Secure Boot option in the BIOS configuration. I made sure the Secure Boot was (and still is) disabled.

(edit) sudo efibootmgr --verbose output
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 000C,000D,000E,0004
Boot0004  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.A.D.A.T.A.        .S.U.6.3.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.L.2.6.2.9.2.7.1.N.E.U.1. . . . . . . . ........BO..NO........o.S.T.1.0.0.0.L.M.0.2.4. .H.N.-.M.1.0.1.M.B.B....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.3.S.X.2.9.J.G.B.3.9.2.6.6.6. . . . . . ........BO
Boot000C* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,3860fedb-cbb4-1b4b-a151-c012fcf4afec,0x22,0x967de)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)


(edit) My /dev/sda SSD partition table is of type GPT, in case this information is relevant. The /dev/sda6 partition (where Windows 7 is) has the boot-bios flag set.

I got Boot Info Script and ran it. This is the result.


I would really appreciate your help and even more if it prevents me from reinstalling Windows 7, I do not even know how I got it working in the first place (until yesterday when I decided to update Lubuntu).

I did as @talaat-etman suggested with great help from @kos too. My list volume output is
Volume 0      G    NO_LABEL    FAT32   Partition   300 MB    Correct     Hidden
...
Volume 2      K                NTFS    Partition   119 GB    Correct     Hidden
...
Volume 4      E                NTFS    Partition   807 MB    Correct     Hidden
Volume 5      D     W7X64ULT_E FAT32   Partition   14 GB     Correct     Hidden

For clarity:

Volume 0 = /dev/sda1 = the /boot/efi partition

Volume 2 = /dev/sda6 = the Windows 7 C:/ partition (installed)

Volume 4 = /dev/sda5 = "Microsoft reserved partition" which is empty, unknown filesystem, msftres flag active

Volume 5 = /dev/sdc  = Live USB stick from which I booted Win7 installer




I opened the "Advanced Options" menu, and opened CMD. I ran X:\sources>bcdboot X:\Windows /s G: /f ALL and also X:\sources>bcdboot X:\Windows /s K: /f ALL just in case, but both outputs were
   BFSVC Error: Failed to set element application device. Status = [c00000bb]


After I followed the steps described in 11., the "Windows Boot Manager" option reappeared, so maybe I'm close. Trying to run it gives an error, though. I took photo of the screen: 

I booted the Boot-Repair CD from a live USB stick. I ran the program, and it said Windows legacy detected. The process continued and it said that the boot had been successfully repaired. It doesn't work though, since I rebooted and the option does not yet appear. It showed a warning before finishing asking if I wanted to continue (I said yes):
    EFI detected. You may want to retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

When it finished, it gave this report and showed this message:
    You can now reboot your computer.
    Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (sda1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file)!

So, I rebooted, added manually such entry in my BIOS configuration and made my PC boot using it. Still only showed my Lubuntu 22.04 on /dev/sda1 and the Lubuntu 20.04 on dev/sdb7.



The paste after the update-grub does not look like output from that command.

"EFI variables are not supported on this system" sounds bad. Did you install Lubuntu in compatability mode?

Thanks, I corrected the link now. As per your question, well, I don't really know... sorry. I just did the usual procedure (flash USB stick, boot it, run installer, basic time/keyboard/etc. config, manual partitioning, and go). Is there any way I can check that so I can answer you?

What is the output of sudo efibootmgr? (This doesn't do anything to your system, just lists the EFI boot info).

Edited and added.

Oh, just so you know, my /dev/sda SSD partition table is of type GPT... I don't know if this important.

Windows restore media might replace the bootloaders, but they are just files, you can copy them (everything from the EFI/Microsoft... on down) from another Windows system  to your system without them, then rerun sudo update-grub and hope they are picked up.

Thanks for adding the efibootmgr info. It looks somewhat corrupt but it's booting from entry 000C which looks OK and is your ubuntu install; that explains why ubuntu boots and that you did not install in compatibility mode. I'd vote for you trying @ubfan1's suggestion if possible.

Thanks so much to you both. I added the bootinfoscript RESULTS.txt in the information. Yes, I definitely will. I will use the same .iso file I used to install Windows 7 and see if that will dow. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Note that BootInfoscript report is now part of Boot-Repair and is updated in Boot-Repair. I still run both as I can run BootInfoscript with a script where Boot-Repair needs a gui. But you can extract the two files from Boot-Repair that are the script and have a much updated bootinfoscript. Since UEFI and gpt drive, Windows fixes must be in UEFI boot mode. Boot Windows repair/recovery drive in UEFI mode. Early Windows 7 ISO did not have an UEFI mode, but later versions did.

Thanks @ubfan1 for your commet. I did as you said, but I don't really know from where I should copy files, and where to leave them. I copied the EFI/Microsoft files from the /dev/sda6 partition (where Win7 is installed) and put them into the /boot/efi/EFI/microsoft folder in the /dev/sda3 partition (Lubuntu 22.04), ran sudo update-grub but no results.

Hi @oldfred and thanks. I ran a live USB stick with Win7 installer. I went to "Advanced options" I think, and clicked the "Repair boot" option. After a few seconds, the PC rebooted, and booted from my usual grub, where "Windows boot manager" still does not appear.

Windows needs an UEFI boot entry, although if /EFI/Microsoft has correct files, grub usually boots using chainload to those. After updating Windows, you have to run sudo update-grub for grub to find Windows boot files with os-prober. You can also add Windows UEFI boot entry with efibootmgr. See IV and example to restore Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Hi, thanks again @oldfred, I did as you said. I manually added the "Windows Boot Manager" like it said in the post you shared. After doing the steps, the option appears in the efibootmgr output, but update-grub still doesn't find it. When rebooting, the option doesn't appear on startup, and when I choose Lubuntu and run efibootmgr again, the "Windows Boot Manager" option I added manually isn't there any more, like it was auto-deleted for some reason.

Did you run the full set of Windows repairs or just create /EFI/Microsoft? Was the Windows entry in UEFI after you updated it, both from efibootmgr and then on reboot? If /EFI/Microsoft does not exist that may be the issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/860729/is-it-possible-to-install-windows-7-alongside-ubuntu-and-windows-10-dualboot & https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510013/cant-boot-to-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-in-uefi

Hello @oldfred and sorry for the delay. I did as it says in this thread you shared. It seemed it would fit my case because it was specific for GPT-partitioned disks, like mine. I did exactly as it said, but it didn't work. The error message was BFSVC Error: Invalid VolumePathNameLegth D:\Windows\  (all of the volume letters were checked). When I rebooted, the Windows Boot Manager option appeared but reuslted in the black screen shown in my question.

Also @oldfred, booting into Lubuntu and mounting /dev/sda1 manually shown that the commands had actually created the files in the EFI/Microsoft/Boot folder, but apparently it's not enough...

Was the error from efibootmgr or from Windows boot? Do not know Windows issues. But all UEFI entries have to refer to a valid partUUID that is the FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags or the ESP.  And Windows has to have whatever boot files BCD etc that it needs in /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP.

I have done it exactly as you indicated. Yes, the error is from Windows boot.

After rebooing by windows installation media,
You can copy BCD files that support booting on either a UEFI-based or a BIOS-based computer from the C:\Windows folder to windows boot drive  or to C drive by the following command:
bcdboot C:\Windows /s X: /f ALL #replace X with boot or windows drive

after then, reboot by lubuntu and update-grub
I usually put the boot files in the boot partition and the Windows partition. if there is any problem in the boot partition, I will boot directly from Windows partition.
Revere to this video to know how to fix UEFI Partition When Windows 10 and 11 Won't Boot.
Revere to this answer to know how to deal with Windows botable USB drive from Ubuntu and Windows, and how to use HBCD_PE to fix BCD problems.

I think you meant "replace X with the EFI partition's letter". Also they should make sure the EFI partition is mounted, which IIRC isn't by default when booting from an installation media. CMD prompt, diskpart, list disk, check the target disk's index number (let's say 1), sel disk 1, list par, check the EFI partition's index number (let's say 2), sel par 2, assign letter x (which probably will be in use already and hosting the installation media's main partition, so maybe assign letter g or whatever) and then use the command replacing X with the correct letter.

Final note: Windows isn't guaranteed to be mounted on C either, so checking from diskpart or running C: + dir perhaps is in order.

Thanks Talaat and @kos for your answers and help. I edited my question with the results. I wasn't sure which dirves was I supposed to chose as origin and destination of the files. In both cases I chose X:/ as source (which I think is where the live Win7 is running) and put them in G:/ (/boot/efi, partition AKA /dev/sda1) and also tried to put them in K:/ (where the Win7 is, the one I can't boot, partition dev/sda6). I think it didn't work.

@Santiago, please try this command: bcdboot K:\Windows /s G: /f ALL and also bcdboot K:\Windows /s K: /f ALL

@Santiago You should've chosen the letter where the installed Windows 7 was as the source letter, however you seemed to have (manually) copied the source files correctly (at least judging from what you said in your last edit to the question), but you didn't rebuild your BCD, which is an entirely different cat to skin. So you should manually remove all the files that you copied and follow the procedure correctly instead (the first command posted by Talaat in the comment above this one is correct, the other one is not), which also recreates the BCD in the right position.

Hello Talaat and @kos it's me again. I did as you said. bcdboot K:\Windows /s G: /f ALL but I get an error: BFSVC Error: Invalid VolumePathNameLegth K:\Windows\  which is really weird because I couldn't find it in the internet... so it's not my lucky weekend. I also tried the second command Talaat suggested, but didn't work either. I tried changing the letters too. Now for some reason (before retrying this) the Windows Boot Manager option appears, but I get the error as shown in the picture (see question). Is all hope lost? Is reinstalling Win7 in /dev/sda6 my only option?

@Santiago Try again. Make sure the EFI partition is clean from all the files that you have moved into it during these attempts (the manual copy + the bcdboot way), boot the installation media again and, this time around, run diskpart and make sure that the letters match, you shouldn't be trying and randomly "changing letters"; the first argument to bcdboot must be the Windows installation folder (C, K or whatever else diskpart reports), the EFI partition must be mounted (you can mount it as I described in the previous comment) and its letter must be the argument to /s.

@Santiago After that, at this point, I'd also boot into the BIOS and remove the Windows entry you previously added (most UEFIs will add a new entry automatically upon reboot)

Hello, I'm back. So sorry for the delay. I did as @kos suggested and it seems to be closer to working. I was indeed choosing the wrong partitions. The new error now was "Failure when initializing library system volume". I read this thread and it said that I shoud set Active my EFI partition. I couldn't because it said that the disk isn't a fixed MBR (my disk is in GPT, like I specified on my question) [continues below]

[continues from above] The solution there was to erase EFI partition and redoing it from Windows. If this works and I can boot Win7, I'll probably won't be able to boot Lubuntu, but I feel it's gonna be possible to make Lubuntu "catch up" after Windows is able to boot, and not the other way around. So, in the first place, can this be a way of booting Win7? And after this, already having a clean functioning EFI+Win7 partitions, is it possible to make my Lubuntu 22.04 on /dev/sda3 catch up and add itself to the boot options?

When installing UEFI boot files, you need to only have one ESP per drive. And if not the default that efibootmgr uses of sda1, you have to specify drive & partition. Not sure how Windows does it but always best to have ESP on same drive as install, if installs are not on same drive.

You can copy BCD files to the same Windows partition (C), reboot by Lubuntu and update grub

Sorry, nothing worked. I will reinstall Windows on the same partition it had before, see what happens. Cheers and thanks for everything

Ok, after quickly looking at boot repair log, i can see you have more than one grub, try loading the grub on sda, i can see it's already installed there, so all you need to do is mark sda1 partition with the boot flag, using gparted for example.
What happens is that the fixed grub containing windows section doesnot get booted.
Also beside boot repair, there is super grub disc too.
Is sdc your live usb stick?
Good luck ! and keep me posted...

Thanks for your suggestions. Yes, /dev/sdc is my USB stick. I think I understand what you are saying. I checked with GParted, and /dev/sda1 has "boot" and "esp" flags, /dev/sda3 (Lubuntu 22.04) has no flags, and /dev/sda6 (Win7) has boot_bios flag. With "fixed grub" you mean /dev/sda1? I'll try Super Grub2 Disk and get back to you.

There is an app too called grub custimizer that custimizes grub within a working distro using a gui. Boot repair repairs only one grub, that's the fixed one. Try putting boot flag to /dev/sda3 too.

Added the point no. 11 with my walk through using the Boot-Repair CD which seems to be close to giving a solution. It shows that maybe I have 2 grubs like you suggested? Couldn't do Grub2 Disk work (the libe USB creator doesn't let me choose its .iso file).

I strongly suggest that you do not use grub-customizer.
